# Rails 4 / i18n / can't pass the locales to another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, locale, rails-i18n

I'm making a simple website with a home page and a contact form. Now I'm trying to make it into 3 languages using the rails-i18n gem, and it was successful on the home page, but now I'm stuck with how to pass the locales from the home page to the contact page. The codes are as below and please let me know if you have any clues.

routes.rb (deleting 2 resources in the scope makes no difference)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'contact' => 'inquiry#contact'
  post 'contact/confirm' => 'inquiry#confirm'
  post 'contact/thanks' => 'inquiry#thanks'

  root 'static_pages#home'
  match '/home', to: 'static_pages#home', via: 'get'

  scope '(:locale)', locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.map(&:to_s).join('|')}/ do
    resources :static_pages
    resources :inquiry
  end

end
```

application_controller.rb (deleting default_url_options makes no difference)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = locale
  end

  def locale
    @locale ||= params[:locale] ||= I18n.default_locale
  end

  def default_url_options(options={})
    options.merge(locale: locale)
  end
end
```

inquiry_controller.rb (when the contact is called, the locale becomes :en which is default)

```
class InquiryController < ApplicationController
  def contact
    @inquiry = Inquiry.new
    render :action => 'contact'
  end

  def confirm
    @inquiry = Inquiry.new(params[:inquiry])
    if @inquiry.valid?
      render :action => 'confirm'
    else
      render :action => 'contact'
    end
  end

  def thanks
    @inquiry = Inquiry.new(params[:inquiry])
    InquiryMailer.received_email(@inquiry).deliver

    render :action => 'thanks'
  end
end
```

_dropdown.html.erb (the dropdown to change the language I added in the home page. It's not added in the contact page)

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Languages <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><%= link_to '英語/English', url_for(controller: controller.controller_name, action: controller.action_name, locale: 'en') %></li>
    <li><%= link_to '中文/Mandarin', url_for(controller: controller.controller_name, action: controller.action_name, locale: 'ma') %></li>
    <li><%= link_to '日本語/Japanese', url_for(controller: controller.controller_name, action: controller.action_name, locale: 'ja') %></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

console (I feel something's wrong...)

```
$ rake routes
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                Controller#Action
         contact GET    /contact(.:format)                         inquiry#contact
 contact_confirm POST   /contact/confirm(.:format)                 inquiry#confirm
  contact_thanks POST   /contact/thanks(.:format)                  inquiry#thanks
            root GET    /                                          static_pages#home
            home GET    /home(.:format)                            static_pages#home
    static_pages GET    (/:locale)/static_pages(.:format)          static_pages#index {:locale=>/en|ma|ja/}
                 POST   (/:locale)/static_pages(.:format)          static_pages#create {:locale=>/en|ma|ja/}
 new_static_page GET    (/:locale)/static_pages/new(.:format)      static_pages#new {:locale=>/en|ma|ja/}
edit_static_page GET    (/:locale)/static_pages/:id/edit(.:format) static_pages#edit {:locale=>/en|ma|ja/}
     static_page GET    (/:locale)/static_pages/:id(.:format)      static_pages#show {:locale=>/en|ma|ja/}
                 PATCH  (/:locale)/static_pages/:id(.:format)      static_pages#update {:locale=>/en|ma|ja/}
                 PUT    (/:locale)/static_pages/:id(.:format)      static_pages#update {:locale=>/en|ma|ja/}
                 DELETE (/:locale)/static_pages/:id(.:format)      static_pages#destroy {:locale=>/en|ma|ja/}
   inquiry_index GET    (/:locale)/inquiry(.:format)               inquiry#index {:locale=>/en|ma|ja/}
                 POST   (/:locale)/inquiry(.:format)               inquiry#create {:locale=>/en|ma|ja/}
     new_inquiry GET    (/:locale)/inquiry/new(.:format)           inquiry#new {:locale=>/en|ma|ja/}
    edit_inquiry GET    (/:locale)/inquiry/:id/edit(.:format)      inquiry#edit {:locale=>/en|ma|ja/}
         inquiry GET    (/:locale)/inquiry/:id(.:format)           inquiry#show {:locale=>/en|ma|ja/}
                 PATCH  (/:locale)/inquiry/:id(.:format)           inquiry#update {:locale=>/en|ma|ja/}
                 PUT    (/:locale)/inquiry/:id(.:format)           inquiry#update {:locale=>/en|ma|ja/}
                 DELETE (/:locale)/inquiry/:id(.:format)           inquiry#destroy {:locale=>/en|ma|ja/}
```

According to a blog page I referred to to set up all of these, the scope thing in routes.rb is supposed to enable access by /en or /ja, etc., it give routing errors. I feel like I didn't get the whole thing right... Any small advice would be appreciated!

Comment: why not put all your routes inside the `:locale` scope ?

Comment: I've tried putting root and home inside the scope but I got en/root, en/home, etc. instead of root/en, home/en, etc... so I deleted them. Or any specific way to put them in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing the link to /contact from href="/contact" to <%= link_to t('view.contact'), url_for(controller: :inquiry, action: :contact) %>